# Duas requisições Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso fazer duas requisições Ajax. uma para minha propria base de dados. a outra é via API. a primeira é para consultar na minha base de dados, se o CNPJ, informado já está cadastrado, a segunda, é para uma URL externa.
A segunda só é para execultar se a primeira consulta vim NULL, se a primeira consulta retornar algum resultado, quero mostrar uma mensagem de CNPJ JA CADASTRADO.

Na minha controller eu fiz o seguinte método:

```
public ActionResult VerificarCnpjJaCadastrado(string cnpj)
        {
            var cliente = _clienteAppService.ContarCpfOuCnpjCadastrado(cnpj);
            if (cliente != null)
            {
                return Json(cliente, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet).Mensagem("CPF|CNPJ Já cadastrado na base de dados", "Já Cadastrado");
            }

            return Json(cliente, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

para ser sincero, eu não sei como fazer para uma requisição vir para esse método, e se retornar `NULL`, fazer a próxima requisição.

Esse aqui é o Ajax que faz a requisição via API;

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Adicionamos o evento onclick ao botão com o ID "pesquisar"
        $('#pesquisar').on('click', function (e) {

            // Apesar do botão estar com o type="button", é prudente chamar essa função para evitar algum comportamento indesejado
            e.preventDefault();

            // Aqui recuperamos o cnpj preenchido do campo e usamos uma expressão regular para limpar da string tudo aquilo que for diferente de números
            var cnpj = $('#Cliente_Cnpj').val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

            // Fazemos uma verificação simples do cnpj confirmando se ele tem 14 caracteres
            if (cnpj.length == 14) {


                // Aqui rodamos o ajax para a url da API concatenando o número do CNPJ na url
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/' + cnpj,
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType:
                        'jsonp', // Em requisições AJAX para outro domínio é necessário usar o formato "jsonp" que é o único aceito pelos navegadores por questão de segurança
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#status').html('<div class="alert alert-info">Buscando CNPJ</div>');
                    },

                    complete: function (xhr) {
                        $('#status').html('<div class="alert alert-success">CNPJ Encontrado</div>');
                        setTimeout(function() { 
                            $('#status').html('');
                        }, 1000);


                        // Aqui recuperamos o json retornado
                        response = xhr.responseJSON;

                        // Na documentação desta API tem esse campo status que retorna "OK" caso a consulta tenha sido efetuada com sucesso
                        if (response.status == 'OK') {

                            // Agora preenchemos os campos com os valores retornados
                            $('#Cliente_RazaoSocial').val(response.nome);
                            $('#Cliente_NomeFantasia').val(response.fantasia);
                            $('#Endereco_Rua').val(response.logradouro);
                            $('#Endereco_Numero').val(response.numero);
                            $('#Endereco_Bairro').val(response.bairro);
                            $('#Endereco_Complemento').val(response.complemento);
                            $('#Endereco_Cep').val(response.cep);

                            //$('#Cliente_Cnae').val(response.atividade_principal);
                            // Aqui exibimos uma mensagem caso tenha ocorrido algum erro
                        } else {
                            alert(response.message); // Neste caso estamos imprimindo a mensagem que a própria API retorna
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Tratativa para caso o CNPJ não tenha 14 caracteres
            } else {
                alert('CNPJ inválido');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Tipo, eu tenho que criar dentro dessa função dois Ajax? tipo

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({R1}) //Ajax 1
$.ajax({R2}) //Ajax 2
}
```

ou algo do tipo:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
            if(ajax1 == null)
               {
               $.ajax({R2})
               }else{("CNPJ JA CADASTRADO")}
           }) //Ajax 1
     //Ajax 2
    }
```

Comment: Basta fazer a outra chamada no else que printa o retorno

Você consegue executar uma requisição AJAX no complete ou no error de outra requisição

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha acho que nu success é melhor.

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus pra ser sincero eu não sei a diferença kkkk então vou confiar em você

Comment: Mas como ficaria? alguém poderia me dar só um pequeno exmplo?

Comment: Edita a pergunta e explica melhor o problema aí pfv

Comment: Editei... não sei se ficou de melhor entendimento